How to change the same column in multiple dataframes to a unique identifier?
I am trying to place a unique ID in the Site.Name column of 8 similar dfs using a list of names. I tried
site<-c("Smith","Sledd Creek","Crooked Creek","Duncan","Mammoth Rurnace","Sugar","Jake Fork","Honker")

for (i in 1:8) {
 EXO[[i]]$Site.Name<-site[i]  
}

but I kept getting the error
Error: object 'EXO' not found
The code below accomplished what I needed, but I want to know if I can do something like this using a for loop or lapply or something similar.
site<-c("Smith","Sledd Creek","Crooked Creek","Duncan","Mammoth Rurnace","Sugar","Jake Fork","Honker")

EXO1$Site.Name<-site[1]  
EXO2$Site.Name<-site[2] 
EXO3$Site.Name<-site[3] 
EXO4$Site.Name<-site[4] 
EXO5$Site.Name<-site[5] 
EXO6$Site.Name<-site[6] 
EXO7$Site.Name<-site[7] 
EXO8$Site.Name<-site[8] 


Are you aiming to create these data frames in your loop, or do you have a list of data frames you want to add this common column to?

These kinds of situation always point to the need to group the data frames together into a list so that you can employ functional programming. The easiest way is to use some tidyverse tools, namely purrr and dplyr:
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map2(list(EXO1, EXO2, EXO3, EXO4, EXO5, EXO6, EXO7, EXO8), site, 
     function(x, y) { mutate(x, Site.Name = y) })

This will iterate through each element of the list of data frames, and each element of the site vector, to include a variable the same string throughout the rows of the given data frame, in the order that is provided.
Please note that I'm not able to test if the output is what you want, as you did not provide any reproducible data for those data frames.

So that command printed each df in the console with the correct site name, but the site names were not saved in the df's.

Yes you need to assign it into a new object, e.g. mydfs <- ... and then you can access them using mydfs$EX01 or mydfs[["EX01"]] and so forth.
